# Rails 3 Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I had this working yesterday, I don't know what I did to break it.

Here are the routes for a RESTful controller:

```
brand_responsibilities    GET    /brands/:brand_id/responsibilities(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"responsibilities"}
brand_responsibilities    POST   /brands/:brand_id/responsibilities(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"responsibilities"}
new_brand_responsibility  GET    /brands/:brand_id/responsibilities/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"responsibilities"}
edit_brand_responsibility GET    /brands/:brand_id/responsibilities/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"responsibilities"}
brand_responsibility      GET    /brands/:brand_id/responsibilities/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"responsibilities"}
brand_responsibility      PUT    /brands/:brand_id/responsibilities/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"responsibilities"}
brand_responsibility      DELETE /brands/:brand_id/responsibilities/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"responsibilities"}
```

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for :responsibility, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :access_request_id, :value => ar.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :brand_id, :value => @brand.id %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But I get a 404 now with this log message:

```
Started POST "/brands/30/responsibilities" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Oct 26 10:47:17 -0400 2010

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/brands/30/responsibilities"):
```

It sure looks like the route matches to me! What am I missing?

Update: I also tried this in the console:

```
rs.recognize_path '/brands/30/responsibilities', :method => :post
```

and the response is:

```
=> {:controller=>"responsibilities", :brand_id=>"30", :action=>"create"}
```

What is my deal?

UPDATE #2:

I found the cause, though I don't know why it's the cause.  I have another field:

```
<%= button_to "Deny", brand_responsibilities_path(@brand, :ar => ar), :remote => true, :method => :delete %>
```

That I was including in the form. I left it out for brevity's sake before because I didn't think it was important. I see that was a bad idea.

Does anybody know why the presence of that line in the form causes the weird routing error?

Comment: Weird! With the info you provided, it should work. Did you restart your server after adding the routes to `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: This probably doesn't help your issue, but is just good to know... you can do <% form_for [@brand, :responsibility] %> to avoid having a hidden field passing the brand id. That will also generate the /brands/:id/responsibilities action in the form. Aside from that, the only explanation for your issue is that there is a route higher in priority (lower in the list of routes) overriding the ones you pasted.

Comment: Yeah, I've restarted and everything. I reconfigured the form to your example Jen, and I saw that too in Bates' Controller in Rails 3 screencast. Still the same thing.  My route is:


  resources :brands do
    resources :responsibilities
  end

There's nothing generic above it or below it in the routes.rb.

Comment: Also, it works from console!


rs.recognize_path '/brands/30/responsibilities', :method => :post
=> {:controller=>"responsibilities", :brand_id=>"30", :action=>"create"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if I am an idiot.

Leaving out that crucial piece of information was a bad idea. Having a button_to within a form is a no-no, it creates a form within a form.

Rookie mistake. Too bad I've been doing this for a long time.  Upvotes to the commenters, sorry for wasting your valuable time.